Array slices are not supported for continuous assignment
I'm trying to index into a 2D array in Verilog like this:
`include "src/elementwise_multiplication.v"
module parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic #(parameter N = 8, parameter M = 2) (
    input wire [N-1:0] a [0:M-1][0:N-1],
    input wire [N-1:0] b [0:M-1][0:N-1],
    output wire [2*N-1:0] result [0:M-1][0:N-1]
    );

    genvar i;
    generate
        // Instantiate elementwise_multiplication modules for each pair of arrays
        for (i = 0; i < M; i = i + 1) begin : instantiate_multiplication
            elementwise_multiplication #(N) inst (
                .a(a[i]),
                .b(b[i]),
                .result(result[i])
            );
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule

Link to EDA Playground.
When I run this command iverilog -g2012
I get this error:
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:14: sorry: Array slices are not yet supported for continuous assignment.
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:14:      : Port 1 (a) of elementwise_multiplication is connected to a[i]
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:15: sorry: Array slices are not yet supported for continuous assignment.
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:15:      : Port 2 (b) of elementwise_multiplication is connected to b[i]
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:16: sorry: Array slices are not yet supported for continuous assignment.
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:16:      : Port 3 (result) of elementwise_multiplication is connected to result[i]
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:14: sorry: Array slices are not yet supported for continuous assignment.
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:14:      : Port 1 (a) of elementwise_multiplication is connected to a[i]
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:15: sorry: Array slices are not yet supported for continuous assignment.
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:15:      : Port 2 (b) of elementwise_multiplication is connected to b[i]
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:16: sorry: Array slices are not yet supported for continuous assignment.
src/parallel_elementwise_multiplication_dynamic.v:16:      : Port 3 (result) of elementwise_multiplication is connected to result[i]
6 error(s) during elaboration.

I'm expecting the code to synthesize, so that I will be able to have dynamic generation of elementwise_multiplication modules.
I want to avoid hardcoding each elementwise_multiplication module. Here is an example of what I want to avoid:
`include "src/elementwise_multiplication.v"
module parallel_elementwise_multiplication #(parameter N = 8) (
    input wire [N-1:0] a [0:N-1],
    input wire [N-1:0] b [0:N-1],
    input wire [N-1:0] c [0:N-1],
    input wire [N-1:0] d [0:N-1],
    output wire [2*N-1:0] result_ab [0:N-1],
    output wire [2*N-1:0] result_cd [0:N-1]
);

    elementwise_multiplication #(N) inst_ab (
        .a(a),
        .b(b),
        .result(result_ab)
    );

    elementwise_multiplication #(N) inst_cd (
        .a(c),
        .b(d),
        .result(result_cd)
    );

endmodule


My answer here might help.  -- I'm too far removed to say for sure.   So, simply... FYI.

im new to verilog. i would appreciate if you could elaborate more. thanks in advance.

Verilog does not support unpack/multi-dimensional arrays in the port list. SystemVerilog does. Simple rename the file extensions from .v to .sv for your file and iverilog would compile it as SytemVerilog

@Greg I renamed the file extensions *.sv, and i still get the same error.

The error message you have shown indicates that the file is still named .v.

@mkrieger1 is there a way to make sure that its .sv? I confident that I changed all .v file extensions to .sv.

@mkrieger1 I tried running it on EDA Playground (with .sv) and I get the same error.

Seems to be an iverilog issue.  All 4 commercial simulators are good with the post on EDA Playground.

I need it to run with iverilog. are there any workarounds?

From its github page: "Icarus Verilog is intended to compile ALL of the Verilog HDL, as described in the IEEE-1364 standard. Of course, it's not quite there yet."  1364 is the plain Verilog standard.  @Greg mentioned that straight Verilog does not support multi-dimensional arrays as ports.  You can use a single dimension, and implicly pack it by defining for yourself the size of the implicit dimension.  For example if you need an 8 element of 8 bit vectors array, then pre pack all 8 inputs into a 64 bit vector, and unpack them inside the target module.

See the answer by @dave_59 here Daves Answer about two dimensions about how to work around the limitation in Verilog.

If it's not obvious by now: iverilog is a Verilog simulator, and doesn't support many SV features. It doesn't matter what your file extension is. It's a great simulator, and you can run a farm of instances to test complex devices without spending MBucks. For simple cases like this, I would convert your code back to plain Verilog. SV's USP is a few Verilog fixes and updates, plus a an entirely new language which (a) should never have been bolted onto Verilog, (b) had already been done much better elsewhere, and (c) exists only because Synopsys was worried about market share.
